# TabHost setCurrentTab only calls oncreate method for Activity in Tab once

Tags: android, tabs

I'm following the example here:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Everything works fine.  The first time I click on each tab, the `oncreate` method for Activity bound to that particular tab is called.  However, subsequent selections of the tab's do not call this oncreate method.

I need to be able to execute oncreate (or another method) on the Activity that is bound to each Tab, when that tab is selected.  I know I can use a `setOnTabChangedListener`, but I am unsure how to get access to the Activity that is bound to the tab, so that I can call the oncreate (or another) method.

Comment: You could put your code in onResume()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of efficiency... that's why your `onCreate` method is not being called twice or more times. The eaiser way to access your activity from your `TabActivity` through the `OnTabChangedListener` is this:

```
public class YourTabActivity extends TabActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle InSavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(InSavedInstanceState);
        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // blablabla

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                if( tabId.equals("the_id_of_your_tab") ){
                    NameOfThatActivity.self.theMethodYouWantToCall();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then, on your child activity, you have something like:

```
public class NameOfThatActivity extends Activity{

    public static NameOfThatActivity self;

    // blah blah blah
    public onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        self = this;
    }

    public void theMethodYouWantToCall(){
        // do what ever you want here
    }
}
```

It's not beauty, but it works fine.

Comment: thanks - that is perfect!  I actually found I could do this in a slightly different way by gaining access to the TabHost from the onCreate() method the first time it is called, and storing a copy of my Activity for access later.  tabHost.setTag(this)  I like your method better, though.

Comment: android is ridiculous state machine!!! lost state of activities in tabs! why android architect team doesnt implement tab like ONE activity with parts, to prevent lost state!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the onStart method in the [Activity class](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), I think you are wanting to override that instead of onCreate (or in addition to, typically you call setContentView only in onCreate)

Answer (score 2):

another method you can call if use TabActivity.getCurrentActivity()

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Cristian, it's a matter of efficiency. 
but you can always use the onResume() method in your child activity instead.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();               
     // do work 

}
```