# How to call the web service only once in android

Tags: android, web-services, tabs

I have three tabs in my view. Every time when I press the each tab some layout will be inflated and a web service call is done. I am populating some data into my inflated view through this web service call. Everything is working fine. But the problem is I don't want to call the web service every time when I press the tab for the second time. Previous data should be populated automatically without making a call to the web service. I don't think I can use onResume() method for this. Googled out many pages to find this answer but nothing is helpful. Please post the code if necessary. Thanks in advance.

These are my workarounds till now.

[TabHost setCurrentTab only calls oncreate method for Activity in Tab once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710222/tabhost-setcurrenttab-only-calls-oncreate-method-for-activity-in-tab-once)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

http://jnastase.alner.net/archive/2010/10/27/handling-orientation-change-in-android.aspx

Comment: Try to save that data (returned from webservice) locally by using static data, Shared Preferences or Sqlite. check for the local data before calling web service.

Answer (score 1):

Your webservice should return some data, keep this data to your local memory and check every time either this data is null or not, if null then call service otherwise inflate from local data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should know the state of your 'call': `not calling`, `pending`, `called`. You must store it somewhere (`activity`, `shared preferences`, `database` etc) then making a call. Now, for data: you should implement some *caching* (again, in `activity`, `shared preferences`, `database` or even in `plain files`).
Then, in any state of a call, you can show data from *cache*, if it exists, and when call is done you can store new data in cache and show it.

Answer (score 0):

whenever any changes made in one tab, store value in some variable, whenever next time the page is initialized, initialize with old selected value. Please  try it out.. It may solve the problem..